# modify/beutify XML file or tags using vbscript?

Tags: xml, vbscript, xsd, xml-parsing

I have an XML file which is in below formate:

```xml
<payments/>
    <payment>
        <payment_type>
        </payment_type>
        <dataforpay>
        </dataforpay>
        <allocations/>
            <allocation>
                <id>
                </id>
                <notfind>
                </notfind>
                <amount>
                </amount>
            </allocation>
    </payment>
```

as its look very advance format, i want to update this format to below using vbscript.....please give suggestions?

```xml
<payments>
    <payment>
        <payment_type>
        </payment_type>
        <dataforpay>
        </dataforpay>
        <allocations>
            <allocation>
                <id>
                </id>
                <notfind>
                </notfind>
                <amount>
                </amount>
            </allocation>
        </allocations>
    </payment>
</payments>
```

Comment: Are you asking, for example to change `<payments/><payment/>` to `<payments><payment/> ... </payments>`?

Comment: Yes, but it is not every time. in one node its <payments/> this should be <payments>.........</payments> .. but <payment></payment> node is already in correct format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below. It finds self-closing tags with name in the plural, and followed by one or more pair of open-close tags with the same name in the singular, and it replaces each self-closing tag with open-close pair, and moves into it all following tags which was matched.

```vb
sCont = ReadTextFile("C:\Test\src.xml", -2)

With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .Global = False
    .MultiLine = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
    Do
        ' pattern to match a self-closing tag with name in the plural followed by one or more pair of open-close tags with the same name in the singular
        .Pattern = "^[\r\n]*(\s*)<(\w+)s(\s+[^>]*)*/\s*>(\s*[\r\n]+)(\s*<\2(?:\s+[^>]*)*>[\s\S]*?</\2>)"
        If Not .Test(sCont) Then Exit Do
        ' replace matched self-closing tag with open-close pair, and moves first matched following tag into it 
        sCont = .Replace(sCont, "$1<$2s$3>$4$5$4$1</$2s>")
        ' pattern to match a pair of open-close tags with name in the plural containing one or more, and followed by one or more pair of open-close tags with the same name in the singular
        .Pattern = "((?:^\s*)<(\w+)s(?:\s+[^>]*)*>\s*[\r\n]+\s*<\2(?:\s+[^>]*)*>[\s\S]*?</\2>\s*[\r\n]+)(^\s*</\2s>\s*[\r\n]+)(\s*<\2(?:\s+[^>]*)*>[\s\S]*?</\2>\s*[\r\n]+)"
        Do While .Test(sCont)
            ' move matched tag with the same name in the singular into
            sCont = .Replace(sCont, "$1$4$3")
        Loop
    Loop
End With

WriteTextFile sCont, "C:\Test\dst.xml", -2

Function ReadTextFile(sPath, iFormat)
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(sPath, 1, False, iFormat)
        ReadTextFile = ""
        If Not .AtEndOfStream Then ReadTextFile = .ReadAll
        .Close
    End With
End Function

Sub WriteTextFile(sCont, sPath, iFormat)
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(sPath, 2, True, iFormat)
        .Write(sCont)
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

See XHTML parsing with RegExp [disclaimer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: Hi, How can we change/replace  '&' with '&amp;' for sCont. i am getting "Parse Error: A semi colon character was expected." when using this function.

Comment: You can do it without regex, use `sCnt = Replace(sCnt, "&", "&amp;")`

Answer (score 0):

The original format is not valid XML because it has 2 root nodes, so I've loaded the file using the standard [`Scripting.FileSystemObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242706%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) to prevent any errors from XML parse errors

```vb
Option Explicit

dim fso: set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
dim stream: set stream = fso.OpenTextFile("input.xml")
dim xml: xml = stream.ReadAll()
stream.close
```

To manipulate the XML, I load it into an [`MSXML2.DomDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms756987(v=vs.85).aspx) with a dummy root node so it's well-formed

```vb
dim xmldoc: set xmldoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument")
xmldoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
xmldoc.async = false
if not xmldoc.loadXML("<root>" & xml & "</root>") then
    WScript.Echo xmldoc.parseError.reason
    WScript.Quit
end if
```

Then I use [XPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256471(v=vs.80).aspx) to query the `payments` node (assuming only one) and the `payment` nodes (assuming more than one)

```vb
dim paymentsNode: set paymentsNode = xmldoc.selectSingleNode("//payments")
dim paymentNodes: set paymentNodes = xmldoc.selectNodes("//payment")
```

Then I iterate through each payment node and then querying the `allocations` node (assuming only one) and the `allocation` nodes (assuming more than one). Each `allocation` node is removed from its parent and added to the `allocations` node. The same is then done with the `payment`.

```vb
dim p
for p = 0 to paymentNodes.length - 1
    dim payment: set payment = paymentNodes.Item(p)
    dim allocationsNode: set allocationsNode = payment.selectSingleNode("./allocations")
    dim allocationNodes: set allocationNodes = payment.selectNodes("./allocation")

    dim a
    for a = 0 to allocationNodes.length - 1
        dim allocation: set allocation = allocationNodes.Item(a)
        allocation.parentNode.removeChild allocation
        allocationsNode.appendChild allocation
    next

    payment.parentNode.removeChild payment
    paymentsNode.appendChild payment
next
```

Because the `payments` node is now a valid root node, I reload the XML at the `payment` level into the `xmldoc` object to remove our temporary `root` node before saving to disk.

```vb
xmldoc.loadXML xmldoc.selectSingleNode("/root/payments").xml
xmldoc.save "output.xml"
```

An alternative to direct node manipulation would be to use an [XSL Transform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms761399%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but again, you'd need to correct for the root node. This may be a better choice if your input XML file is large.

Comment: thanks for the help. Its good to know this. In my case I have large file with lots of node. from which some are in good formates and some are not. I have just give example for the payments node. i do have lots of different node which is same as payments node. I need to do this for all the node and for all the files? its may fail because some files are in correct format as well. So if is their any way like you suggest XSL Transform then please help me hear.